# error while establishing connection with sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to connect to sqlServer. For this I am using following code:

```
string server = "1.1.1.1,1433";
var stringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
                    {
                        UserID = "id",
                        Password = "pass",
                        MultipleActiveResultSets = true,
                        DataSource = server,
                        NetworkLibrary = "DBMSSOCN",
                        InitialCatalog = "iCatalog"
                    };


using (var con = new SqlConnection(stringBuilder.ToString()))
{
    try
    {
        con.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Connected");
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exception.Message);
    }
}
```

But when programm trying to open connection I get exception "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing connection to sql Server....". And if I change ipAddress and port to serverName and instance like this:

```
var server = @"MSSQL01\SQLENTW";
```

I am able to connect to server. ConnectionString is like in connectionstrings.com. So can anybody point me, where I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you actually running SQL server on port 1433?  As you are not using the default instance name, it will be by default running on a randomly assigned port not 1433.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string server = "1.1.1.1:1433";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your machine is running multiple instances of SQL Server . **Eg. MACHINENAME\SQLEXPRESS, MACHINENAME\MSSQLSERVER, etc**

When you give IP address, it connects to default instance. Since it is not enabled with TCP/IP, it is returning error. You can go to sql Server configuration(Configuration Tools-> SQL Server Configuration utility), and check the tcp enabled for all instances.

Comment: Can you explain where exactly it is. I'm in sql server configuration manager and cannot find it there

Comment: in Config Manager -> SQL Server Network Configuration -> Protocols then y can see the protocols right side. Click all the netwrk configuration and enable tcp/ip

Comment: It was active all the time

Answer (score 0):

What about adding the instance name along?

```
1.1.1.1\SQLENTW,1433
```

In addition to the above use below spinet to find on which port the SQLServer is listening to

```
DECLARE @PORT nvarchar(20), @key nvarchar(100)  
IF CHARINDEX('\',@@SERVERNAME,0) <>0  
BEGIN  
           SET @KEY = 'SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MICROSOFT SQL SERVER\' +@@SERVICENAME+  
                                                                                           '\MSSQLSERVER\SUPERSOCKETNETLIB\TCP'  
END  
ELSE  
BEGIN  
          SET @KEY = 'SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLSERVER\SUPERSOCKETNETLIB\TCP'  
END  

EXEC MASTER..XP_REGREAD @ROOTKEY='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @KEY=@KEY, @VALUE_NAME='TCPPORT', @VALUE=@PORT OUTPUT  
SELECT @PORT
```

Comment: have you checked the port number?